# macOS dedicate USB-device to specific application

Tags: macos, usb, hid

I'm trying to understand if (and if so, how) it's possible to dedicate a HID (USB-card reader for NFC cards) to a specific application in macOS.

The card reader acts as a keyboard, sending the number of the card to whatever is open in macOS. I'm trying to get that USB-device locked to a specific application (e.g. firefox, chrome etc).

I really have no idea where to start looking for this. Hence I'm posting here for any help in the right direction.

Googling "Dedicate USB device to app" etc gave nothing useful.

macOS version 10.14.5 (18F132) (Mojave).

Answer (score 0):

The way applications communicate to USB devices is [IOKit framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html). You could write it as service if you want to lock applications anywhere. And you need to know about [launchd](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) (Launch Daemon). It manages all your background service.